# How to return a list of values ​to the post?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-mvc-5

I'm new to this and I don't know how to do it, I hope you help me

I am using a listbox in my view to use a multiselect. It happens that when selecting them and creating them, it only takes the first value of the selected product, but I want it to capture all the selected values.

In my controller I do the following

```
var producto=db.productos.select(x=> new { idprod=x.id_prod, nombre=nombre_prod}).tolist();
ViewBag.producto=new multiselect(producto,"idprod","nombre");
```

In my site

```
@html.listbox(model=>model.idprod, viewbag.producto as multiselectlist)
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. The syntax of your code looks invalid. Please fix it and provide a [mre].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to use an expression to represent the object property, you could try to use `Html.ListBoxFor`, instead of `Html.ListBox`.

Please refer the following sample:

```
public class Customer
{
    public string CustomerName { get; set; }

    public string[] FavouriteFood { get; set; }
}
//used to add listbox items
public class Food
{
    public int FoodId { get; set; }
    public string FoodName { get; set; }
}
```

Controller:

```
    public IActionResult CreateSurvey()
    {
        //listbox items:
        ViewBag.FoodList = new List<Food>()
        {
            new Food(){ FoodId=101, FoodName="Meat"},
            new Food(){FoodId=102, FoodName="Fruit"},
            new Food(){FoodId=103, FoodName="Fish"}
        }; 
        return View();
    }
    [HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public IActionResult CreateSurvey(Customer customer)
    {
        ViewBag.FoodList = new List<Food>()
        {
            new Food(){ FoodId=101, FoodName="Meat"},
            new Food(){FoodId=102, FoodName="Fruit"},
            new Food(){FoodId=103, FoodName="Fish"}
        };

        //loop through the selected value and do something
        return View();
    }
```

Code in the View:

```
@model netcore5.Models.Customer
 
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-4">
        <form asp-action="CreateSurvey">
            <div asp-validation-summary="ModelOnly" class="text-danger"></div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label asp-for="CustomerName" class="control-label"></label>
                <input asp-for="CustomerName" class="form-control" />
                <span asp-validation-for="CustomerName" class="text-danger"></span>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label asp-for="FavouriteFood" class="control-label"></label>
                @Html.ListBoxFor(model =>model.FavouriteFood, new SelectList((List<Food>)ViewBag.FoodList, "FoodId","FoodName") )
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <input type="submit" value="Create" class="btn btn-primary" />
            </div>
        </form>
    </div>
</div>
```

The result like this:

[image]

If you want to use `Html.ListBox()` method, change the related code as below:

```
   @Html.ListBox("FavouriteFood", new SelectList((List<Food>)ViewBag.FoodList, "FoodId","FoodName") )
```

Then, in the action method, we can also get the selected values.